# Represent G as a product of two proper subgroups, at least one of which is normal. Find the order of G without listing all itself elements.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, permutations, normal-subgroups

I don't really know where to start with this question - an instructive answer would be appreciated!

Let $G=\langle (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9), (1,8,9,4,2,3,7,5,6) \rangle $Represent $G$ as a product of two proper subgroups,  at least one of which is normal. Find the order of $G$ without listing all itself elements.

I thought about taking $\langle(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)\rangle$ as a proper subgroup, but I couldn't work out whether it was proper or not in the context of G. Also, it doesn't help with the rest of the question!

Comment: Are we to "guess" that $\;G\;$ is a subgroup of $\;S_9\;$ ... **or what**?

Comment: It certainly appears to be set up that way.

Comment: The question doesn't give much instruction.

Answer (score 1):

**Hints.**  Take $A = \langle (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)\rangle$ and $B = \langle (1,8,9,4,2,3,7,5,6)\rangle$.  Then show that $A$ is normal in $G$.  Use that fact to show that $G = AB$. Determine the orders of $A$ and $B$, and then use the formula $\mid G\mid = \mid AB\mid = \frac{\mid A\mid\mid B\mid}{\mid A\cap B\mid}$.   For this, you'll need to compute the intersection $A\cap B$.

Comment: thanks I will give it a go!

Comment: Can we show that A is normal, by just simply using the fact that it is a cyclic permutation, therefore a^-1Ga=G? Following this I am not really too sure what to do :/

Comment: To show that $A$ is normal, you just need to show that conjugating its generator $a = (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)$ by the other generator $b = (1,8,9,4,2,3,7,5,6)$ for $G$ results in a permutation that is in $A$, which is to say that it is a power of the generator $a$. In other words, find an integer $k$ such that $b^{-1}ab = a^k$.